# Display Flex Items Align Center

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make it so the second section or the first section will align center with the top.

What I don't understand is the relationship between items with display flex vs items that have display block.

**First Question:** Is there a way with flex so the top logo doesn't look "off" center compared to the centered text in the second section?

Link To Pen: https://codepen.io/skella1/pen/vYZLdVN

```
<div class="header">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" alt="">
  
  <p>Text Goes Here</p>
</div>
<div class="secHeader">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>This is a page to login</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="login">
    <p style="padding-right: 10px;">Login</p>
    <input type="text">
    <button>Login</button>
  </div>
</div>


body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.header {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;
  img {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
.secHeader {
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
  }
}
.content{
    background: url("http://www.placebear.com/500/300") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  .login {
    width: 100%;    
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you narrow it down to one question? (Otherwise, you risk downvotes and closed questions.)

Comment: First Question: Is there a way with flex so the top logo doesn't look "off" center compared to the centered text in the second section?

Comment: Well you have a flex parent with two child elements and justify-content as space between. You're placing a margin of 0 auto on that child element so it's going to look off with the logic. Make your image logo justify-content: center in the flex parent, then pull the text out of the box model using position absolute and place it using positing top/left or right...

Answer (score 1):

Center the image using justify-content: center on the flex parent element and then set the P elements position to absolute and position it using the top/right properties.

Right now you have two elements that are taking up space in the flex parent elements width. The image and the P tags content. Using `justify-content: space-between` will place the remainder of the width the elements do not use, between them. In turn skewing the look of the image from being in the center regardless of your margin set to 0 auto, as *that* only places it in the center of the space it takes up from the parent.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;
}
.header p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 20px;
}

.secHeader {
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
}
.secHeader h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.content {
  background: url("http://www.placebear.com/500/300") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.content .login {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" alt="">
  
  <p>Text Goes Here</p>
</div>
<div class="secHeader">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>This is a page to login</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="login">
    <p style="padding-right: 10px;">Login</p>
    <input type="text">
    <button>Login</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to Question 1)** A really quick fix to this was using the `transform` property in CSS to center the image with respect to the current position

**Answer to Question 2)** Simply set the `max-width` property on the `.content` class to prevent the scrolling you talked about

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.header {
  height: 50px;
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0px;
  img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform:translate(50%,0%);   /* MODIFIED CODE HERE */
  }
}
.secHeader {
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
  }
}
.content{
    background: url("http://www.placebear.com/500/300") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width:100vw;       /* MODIFIED CODE HERE */
  position: relative;
  .login {
    width: 100%;    
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0px;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're insisting on using flexbox for the header, what you can do is the following:

```html
<div class="header">
  <div> 
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x50" alt="">
  </div>
    <div class="text-right">
        <p>Text Goes Here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.header {
  height: 50px;
  display:flex;
  padding: 0px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  div {
    flex:1;
  }
  div.text-center {
    text-align:center;
  }
  div.text-right{
    text-align:right;
  }
}
```

Please note that this is just a workaround, flexbox is not the only solution here. You might use `position:absolute` for this.